# Can't seem to override a checkout in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I can't seem to toverride a checkout in SharePoint 2010.  I am using SP1 and PowerPivot, and an excel spreadsheet is checked out by another user.  I have also used the SharePoint Farm Account, still nothing.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) go into the document library and make sure the account your using has permission to override if you don't have "full control" set it that way.  Test to see if override works if not try #2

2)Check document library settings/versioning settings and make sure content approval is no.